# I want convert image to pdf(high quality) but in my program image displayed as cropped in my pdf

Tags: java, itext

When i run this program the image will converted in pdf but the given output pdf is not match to the image because it is cropped.I use iText library.

```
    import java.io.FileOutputStream;
    import java.io.IOException;

import com.itextpdf.text.Document;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter;
import com.itextpdf.text.Image;


public class demo {
  public static void main(String ... args) {
    Document document = new Document();
    String input = "d:/PDFCONV/ho.png"; // .gif and .jpg are ok too!
    String output = "d:/PDFCONV/pdfho.pdf";
    try {
      FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(output);
      PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, fos);
      writer.open();
      document.open();
      document.add(Image.getInstance(input));
      document.close();
      writer.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Not a java issue. Please see itextpdf documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Your question went unnoticed because it wasn't tagged as an iText question. I fixed this.

You can fix your problem by adapting the size of the page in PDF. Currently you define the page size implicitly:

```
Document document = new Document();
```

You are not passing any argument, hence the default page size is used: `PageSize.A4`.

If you want to define another page size, you need to add a `Rectangle` as parameter. Incidentally, the `Image` class extends the `Rectangle` class, hence you can do this:

```
Image image = Image.getInstance(input);
Document document = new Document(image);
```

Now you can add the image like this:

```
image.setAbsolutePosition(0, 0);
document.add(image);
```

If you don't set the absolute position to `x = 0, y = 0`, your image will still be cropped on account of the margins. As an alternative you could define margins with zero width/height, but this will do:

```
Image image = Image.getInstance(input);
Document document = new Document(image);
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, fos);
document.open();
image.setAbsolutePosition(0, 0);
document.add(image);
document.close();
```

Please *remove* the lines `writer.open();` and `writer.close();` from your code. (Why are they there? from which example did you copy those lines?) Please follow the advice given by fildor and [read the documentation](http://developers.itextpdf.com/)!

Comment: As an addendum: you can also resize/scale the image instead of resizing the page.